# How to change birghtness of bg img in a page builder div without effecting child elements and change the brightness on hover

Tags: html, css

**Please note:** *my client is using a page builder plugin for Wordpress, so we are unable to change the structure of the html and can only make modifcations to the css!*

I need to reduce the brightness of our background image to 40% without effecting the text in our child elements. Filters or background rgba are both acceptable. On hover, the brightness needs to change to 100%.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6 vc_col-has-fill">
    <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1493898173136">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element">
                <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                    <p>OUR TITLE</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                    <p>OUR TEXT</p>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is an excerpt of the CSS which we need to modify:

```
.wpb_column{position:relative;}
.vc_column_container{padding-left:0;padding-right:0;}
.vc_col-sm-6{float:left;}
.vc_column-inner{padding:100px 20%;background:url(http://ourdomain.com/bild.jpg)}
```

I'm pretty sure we can fix this using the :before and :after psuedo elements, but everything I've tried so far hasn't worked out.

*I know there are a number of similar questions out there, but please don't mark as a duplicate as the page builder html makes this a special case!*

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on hover background-image brightness

add this below class in custom  css

```
.vc_column-inner:hover {
         -webkit-filter: brightness(1.3);
    -moz-filter: brightness(1.3);
    -o-filter:  brightness(1.3);
    -ms-filter:  brightness(1.3);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Shital Marakana's answer works. This is just another method of doing what you're looking for.

You can add a dark gradient to the picture and when on hover just remove that gradient.

```css
.vc_column-inner {
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  
  background: 
    /* top, transparent red */
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
    ),
    /* bottom, image */
    url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/owl1.jpg);
}

.vc_column-inner:hover {
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/owl1.jpg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6 vc_col-has-fill">
    <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1493898173136">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element">
                <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                    <p>OUR TITLE</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                    <p>OUR TEXT</p>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer but due to the page builder plugin, the background image is dynamic and I can only append the CSS